# After installing IIS Manager, must I restart before I can stop the Default Web Site and start a new one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, iis, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Or is there some way I can install IIS and IIS Manager without needing to restart?

I'm using CloudFormation to create a web stack in AWS. The template installs IIS and IIS Manager and then attempts to create various sites via Powershell. The scripts in the tempalte fail because the Default Web Site cannot be stopped and a new site cannot be started until after the computer restarts.

When I say "cannot be stopped" I mean if I try to stop it in IIS Manager, IIS Manager freezes. If I try to do it in Powershell (stop-website "Default Web Site"), Powershell freezes. And iisreset results in this error message: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. (2147943453, 8007041d)

After I restart the computer, I can stop it via IIS Manager or Powershell.

I'd like to run my scripts in one go without having to restart.

Here is the scripts section of my CloudFormation template:

```
"<script>\n",
    "powershell.exe add-windowsfeature web-webserver -includeallsubfeature -logpath $env:temp\\webserver_addrole.log \n",
    "powershell.exe add-windowsfeature web-mgmt-tools -includeallsubfeature -logpath $env:temp\\mgmttools_addrole.log \n",
    "cfn-init.exe -v -s ", {"Ref" : "AWS::StackId"}, " -r WebServerLaunchConfiguration --region ", {"Ref" : "AWS::Region"}, "\n",
"</script>\n",
"<powershell>\n",
    "new-website -name SomeWebsite -port 80 -physicalpath c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\SomeWebsite -ApplicationPool \".NET v4.5\" -force \n",
    "stop-website -name \"Default Web Site\" \n",
    "New-WebBinding -name SomeWebsite -IPAddress \"*\" -Port 80 -HostHeader ", {"Ref" : "SomeWebisteHostHeader"}, " \n",
    "New-WebBinding -name SomeWebsite -IPAddress \"*\" -Port 80 -HostHeader ", {"Ref" : "PreviewSomeWebisteHostHeader"}, " \n",
    "start-website -name SomeWebsite \n",
    "new-website -name SomeWebsiteApi -port 80 -physicalpath c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\SomeWebsiteApi -ApplicationPool \".NET v4.5\" -force; Sleep 5 \n",
    "Get-WebBinding -name SomeWebsiteApi -port 80 | Remove-WebBinding; Sleep 5\n",
    "New-WebBinding -name SomeWebsiteApi -IPAddress \"*\" -Port 80 -HostHeader ", {"Ref" : "SomeWebsiteApiHostHeader"}, " \n",
    "New-WebBinding -name SomeWebsiteApi -IPAddress \"*\" -Port 80 -HostHeader ", {"Ref" : "PreviewSomeWebsiteApiHostHeader"}, " \n",

    "start-website -name SomeWebsiteApi \n",
    "iisreset \n",
"</powershell>"
```

I am using Amazon's generic Windows Server 2012 ami: Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM-English-64Bit-Base-2018.07.11 (ami-490b5831)

Comment: Does it work better if you try `Get-Website -Name "Default Web Site" | Remove-Website`?

Comment: Oddly enough, this did allow me to remove the Default Web Site. I've clarified my question, though. I need to be able to start a new one and even though this allows me to remove the Default site, I still cannot add a new one.

Comment: That is odd. Try setting the `-HostHeader` parameters for your new sites to valid URLs, maybe? If that doesn't work, try creating an Application pool for your new sites as well instead of using one of the default ones.

Comment: Oh, in the real code, the host headers are URIs.

Comment: Great - please share when you figure this out, thanks!